# Split an interval

Tags: math, set, intervals

Ok I need to split an interval into n number of unequal sub intervals, whose interval lengths are in increasing order.

Lets say I have an interval (10,90)

I need n sub intervals.  Lets say n=4

The need sub intervals like (10,20), (20,35), (35,55), (55,90)

The sub interval lengths must be in increasing order

How do I do this??

Comment: Good question, I mean 'how do I do this ?' is a good question.  How would you do this ?  Show at least some evidence that you have tried to solve your problem yourself.  We're here to help, not to do your work for you.

Comment: Well.. I needed this for a lua program.  I actually started specifying the sub intervals manually. I have some specific values for n and the original interval you see, so manual splitting was not too difficult... Ugly, yes, but effective..    
Still I thought there would be a good mathematical solution for this,  tried googling a lot and finally resorted to posting a question here.  
Hopefully I can find a good solution.

Comment: there are infinitely many such sub-interval sequences. You want ANY such sequence of subintervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any monotonic increasing and convex function to build intervals. For example, quadratic function gives us such expression:

DividingValue[i=1..n-1] = A + Round(i^2 * (B-A)/(n^2))

where (A, B) is your interval.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Guess my math is too rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, choose intervals of length 1, 2, 3, .... So in your example of splitting [10, 90] you would have `[[10], [11,12], [13,14,15], [16..90]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)
I'm using MBO's solution though. More generalized.